# Unable to access element using Scrapy Python

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am trying to access some information on Trulia, more specifically the mortgage estimate. I am trying to make this happen only using scrapy or bs4 but unsuccessful. No matter what I try I can't seem to get that attribute even though it appears to me its not dynamically loaded? I Still tried with scrapy-splash but to no avail. Here is my code right now:

```
class TruliaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.trulia.com/p/oh/bedford/59-john-st-bedford-oh-44146--1009668993'
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for item in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(
                item,
                self.parse_single_item,
                meta={
                    "handle_httpstatus_list": [302],
                },
            )

    def parse_single_item(self, response):
        print("=================== STARTING ====================")
        estimate = response.xpath('.//*[@id="main-content"]')
        print(estimate)
```

I have tried all kinds of variations to get the attribute and im starting to give up. Is selenium the only way to go? I can't even seem to get main-content which is one of the outer divs of this attribute. Please help.

Comment: you mean the string `$135,000`  or the `918/mo`

Comment: @Alexander the 918/mo

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure that value is calculated using javascript you will either need to do the calculation yourself or use selenium i guess

Comment: @Alexander but if its using JavaScript shouldn't Splash be able to get that?

Comment: You would think, but not sure, I have never used splash before.